# Distributing data across various BigQuery tables

Tags: google-bigquery, etl

My application generates one log file every 3 min per server with various event types. 
I need to ingest data to BigQuery to various 100+ tables, depending on event types.

Currently, we run in the house ETL process, that split source file into N files followed by data ingestion, but we want to replace it with something lighter.

I was thinking about loading data to the temporary table first, then running N queries copying data to the destination table base on the source event type. But with 30 TB daily, running 100+ queries against the same source could be expensive.

I can not use the partition for 100+ tables in question since we use time range decorator with various business ETL workflow to incrementally crunch the data.

Comment: Consider me thinking aloud, could the temp table be integer range partitioned, just so that you have a cheap way to read each partition and insert to the persistent tables (which are date partitioned)

Comment: Why would not be feasible for you to use partitioned and clustered tables ?

Answer (score 1):

Loading data to the temp table followed by queries distributing data to the various table looks like one viable option, assuming that your temp table is partition and clustered on fields used in where clause distribution If your event type is a number you may consider using integer range partitioning as suggested by @Yun Zhang.

Alternatively, you can use [BqTail](https://github.com/viant/bqtail) Big Query data loader and transformer.
In that case, data ingestion workflow would look like:

myrule.yaml

```
When:
  Prefix: "/logs/"
  Suffix: ".avro"
Async: true
Batch:
  Window:
    DurationInSec: 90
Dest:
  Prefix: /logs/
  Pattern: '/logs/.+/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})/.+'
  Parameters:
    - Name: TableSuffix
      Expression: $1$2$3
  Table: myproject:mydataset.logs_${TableSuffix}
  Transient:
    Dataset: temp
  Schema:
    Template: 'myproject:mydataset.template'
    Split:
      ClusterColumns:
        - eventType
        - nested.otherColumn
      Mapping:
        - When: eventType in (1,2) AND nested.otherColumn > 0
          Then: myproject:mydataset.logs_xxx_${TableSuffix}
        - When: eventType in (3,4) AND nested.otherColumn > 0
          Then: myproject:mydataset.logs_yy_${TableSuffix}
        - When: nested.otherColumn == 0
          Then: myproject:mydataset.logs_zz_${TableSuffix}
OnSuccess:
  - Action: delete
```

You can use this workflow to either run BqTail in stand-alone mode

```
bqtail -r=myrule.yaml -s=someDataURL -X
```

or use the rule in serverless BqTail mode, where each file upload to Google Storage triggers an event to BqTail process.

Finally, you may find '[Loading & transforming data to BigQuery at scale](https://medium.com/@adrianwit/loading-and-transforming-data-to-big-query-at-large-scale-baa328687d82)' handy.